# How to assign a value returned from flask somewhere else in python file?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using flask to return a dict as following:

```
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/calculate', methods=['POST'])

def itemadd():
  thisDictionary = {}
  body = request.get_json()
  total = str(getAnswer("payload","6148ece5989a301f24ee9934")) 
  thisDictionary["value"] = total
  return thisDictionary

if __name__ == '__main__':
  application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I want to use `thisDictionary` somewhere else in the file, for example:

```
newDictionary = thisDictionary
```

Comment: You can't, `itemadd` is a route, hence it must return a proper view as a response. It can, however, change a global "state" object. Whether this is a good design choice is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Put `thisDictionary` into global scope.

```py
application = Flask(__name__)

thisDictionary = {}

@application.route('/calculate', methods=['POST'])
def itemadd():   
    body = request.get_json()
    total = str(getAnswer("payload","6148ece5989a301f24ee9934")) 
    thisDictionary["value"] = total
    return thisDictionary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: `thisDictionary` does not even need to be global as it is not being assigned to inside `itemadd` and it should also not be returned from the function (unless it should actually be the response)